# ListBox contextMenu SubItem Click

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, listbox

I have `ListBox` with `ContextMenu`, I have configured `MenuItem` to works only if I click in selected item.

This is XAML code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MessagesLb" Grid.Column="1" Margin="241,100,22.4,50" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionMode="Extended">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="Copia" Click="MessagesLbCopySubMi_Click" />
                                <Separator/>
                                <MenuItem Header="Dettagli" />
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItems.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{x:Null}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I tried to add `Click` event in my `MenuItem` but **it doesn't work.**

Example:

```html
<MenuItem Header="Copia" Click="MessagesLbCopySubMi_Click" />
```

```
private void MessagesLbCopySubMi_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Click event done");
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: *"MenuItem to works only if I right click in it"* - you don't need such a trigger. `ListBox` will only create `ListBoxItem` for actual items, when assigning context menu to `ListBoxItem` you already fulfill this condition, i.e. you have to right click `ListBoxItem` to see context menu. You can assign another context menu to `ListBox` itself, this will be then shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the `ContextMenu` as a resource:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MessagesLb" Grid.Column="1" Margin="241,100,22.4,50" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0" FontSize="14" FontWeight="SemiBold" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionMode="Extended">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="cm">
            <MenuItem Header="Copia" Click="MessagesLbCopySubMi_Click" />
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="Dettagli" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItems.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{x:Null}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Do you know why OP code doesn't work? aka what is the mistake he made?

Comment: Why should he? Why doesn't anything complain? I am trying his code and I can give any name to `Click` event handler (non existing one), nothing throws error. I have feeling it's something similar to adding event handler to style defined in the dictionary... like event handler is never wired.

Comment: I mean I can define `ContextMenu` in place for anything normally. Is it the combination of "context menu in style" what [makes the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30387649/1997232)? Still interesting is why: why not possible and why no error.

Comment: The XAML processor is unable to hook up event handlers when you define the ContextMenu inline directly in the setter. The solution is to define the ContextMenu as a resource as per my answer.

Comment: I tried your solution and it works, Thanks man!!
Switching from winform to wpf has its downsides..